# Java Junit throwing the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.junit.runner.Description

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, java-17

I have a few Junit test cases written specific for my application in Java which was working pretty fine. Now all of a sudden I am unable to run it and getting following error in my `Intellij IDE`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.junit.runner.Description org.junit.runner.Description.createTestDescription(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String)'
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.buildRequest(JUnit4TestRunnerUtil.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I am not sure whats causing the issue. Following are some of the specifications related to the project:

1. Java Version: 17
2. I have following dependency in my Maven POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please let me know what could be wrong here and how to fix this?

Comment: Try to use this version <version>4.10</version> of junit

Comment: At first sight it looks like you might be mixing multiple, incompatible versions of JUnit libraries.

Comment: @Nemanja Thanks for your response. I tried this but this does not seem to fix the issue and same issue still exists.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks a lot for your response. Actually, in my project, I have not added any dependency related to Junit. It's being picked up from the parent `bom` project where we have all dependencies and respective versions.

Comment: Which version of Junit 4 are you using? I recommend to use the most recent version 4.13.2 ... or move to JUnit Jupiter (aka JUnit 5)...

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to add dependencies in **pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

2. Run the command, to install the dependencies in the project

```
mvn clean install
```

3. On the Maven icon, make sure that other JUnit dependencies are not colluding.

[image]